# dataflow output to neo4j using jdbcIO vs java driver

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I'm currently working on a setup that uses Google Cloud Dataflow to transform data and save into a Neo4j Database hosted on a Compute Engine VM. The current setup uses a JdbcIO to write to Neo4j by running a prepared statement, but it seems also possible to use a Neo4j driver directly in Java, which allows more flexibility on creating the query dynamically.

I wonder if anyone had compared the 2 approaches and notice any differences? I would guess the Jdbc approach would be more efficient since it only need to run the prepared statement, but that is just my guess.

**Update**
I'm going to post my findings as I experiment more with the two methods

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: we ends up developing a customized plugin that deploys to our neo4j database. the plugin will take-in string consist of raw json objects and create the nodes and relationships accordingly. in order to achieve better performance, we used a windowing and combine transformation in the pipeline to batch all queries received in 10 seconds into one big query, and send to neo4j once. we also used in-memory cache in the plugin to boost performance. so far it was able to match our needs

Comment: Can I ask which Neo4J API you used to perform the writes?

Comment: We are using the `GraphDatabaseAPI` from `org.neo4j.kernel.internal.GraphDatabaseAPI`

Answer (score 0):

One difference I found was that when using JdbcIO, I run into a deadlock when multiple transaction is trying to write to the same node at the same time. However that issue did not occur when using Neo4j driver directly.